# SOQL Sub Query to retrieve the Owner Name

Tags: soql, tasks, subquery

I am trying to retrieve the Tasks associated with the contact by doing the Sub Query like below

```
Select firstname,lastname,(SELECT Id,Subject,Owner.Name FROM Tasks where Status = 'Completed' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) from Contact where AccountId ='001U000000AY5VrIAL'
```

I am trying to get the Owner Name of the Task associated with the Contact but I get back is

[image]

How can I just the get Owner Name in the Sub query so I can use them in lightning datatable

Comment: when you execute a query in console that's how you see it on interface but when executed in apex it will return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to post process the result - the owner name is there, but you will need to iterate through the array to extract it.

The reason you can't see it is because the query viewer is not capable of showing deeply nested objects - you need to serialize it to JSON and then examine that.

I wrote this little query to get the output below:

```
Contact[] contacts = [Select firstname,lastname,
                       (SELECT Id,Subject,Owner.Name FROM Tasks where Status = 'Completed' 
                        ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) from Contact WHERE Id = '003a000002ANxERAAL'];

System.debug(JSON.serialize(contacts));
```

Here is the data structure of what you are looking for (minus attributes objects):

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Joelle",
    "LastName": "Holman",
    "Id": "003a000002ANxERAAL",
    "Tasks": {
      "totalSize": 1,
      "done": true,
      "records": [
        {
          "WhoId": "003a000002ANxERAAL",
          "Id": "00T01000005NxuOEAS",
          "Subject": "Call",
          "OwnerId": "005a000000BqTTkAAN",
          "RecordTypeId": "0120c0000018JUYEA2",
          "Owner": {
            "Id": "005a000000BqRRkAAN",
            "Name": "Caspar Harmer"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Also, it's probably easier to refer directly to the `Tasks` list from the contacts.

This code:

```
System.debug(JSON.serialize(contacts[0].Tasks));
```

Outputs:

```
"WhoId": "003a000002ANxERAAL",
"Id": "00T01000005NxuOEAS",
"Subject": "Call",
"OwnerId": "005a000000BqTTkAAN",
"RecordTypeId": "0120c0000018JUYEA2",
"Owner": {
  "Id": "005a000000BqRRkAAN",
  "Name": "Caspar Harmer"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, The issue is when I am trying to retrieve Owner[0].Name in the lightning component it throws the undefined error. I posted a different question on this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339687/retrieve-owner-name-from-the-sub-query-to-use-in-datatable

Comment: From the data structure above there is no Owner[0].Name - just Owner.Name - but I think you are good, sfdcfox sorted you out, correct?