# Retrieve Owner Name from the Sub Query to use in Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, lightning-datatable, subquery

I am trying to get the Owner Name of the Task that is associated with the contact and display it in the lightning component. The Sub Query for retrieving the Tasks associated with contact is below

```
List<Contact> Conlist = [Select id,Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c,(SELECT Id,Subject,Owner.Name FROM Tasks where Status = 'Completed' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) from Contact where AccountId =: recordId and Key_contact__c = true];
return Conlist;
```

Now I am trying to use the Conlist in the `lightning:datatable` like

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) 
    { 
        component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url',
             typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'ContactName' }, target: '_blank'}},
            {label: 'Activity Subject', fieldName: 'ActivitySubject', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Owner Name', fieldName: 'OwnerName', type: 'text'}
        ]);
        
        var ConList = component.get("c.getRelatedList");
        ConList.setParams
        ({
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        
        ConList.setCallback(this, function(data) 
        {          
            var state = data.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var records = data 
                .getReturnValue()
                .map((row) => ({
                    ContactName : row.Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c,
                    linkName: '/'+row.Id,
                    ActivitySubject: row && row.Tasks && row.Tasks.length ? row.Tasks[0].Subject : '',
                    OwnerName : row.Tasks[0].Owner[0].Name
                               }));
                component.set('v.ContactList', records);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(ConList);
    }
})
```

I get the below error in the lightning component How to get the name of the Owner here and display in the table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent references are not an Array, but a simple Object. No need to use `[0]`.

```
row.Tasks[0].Owner.Name
```

Comment: Yes I tried that too but got error , `Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]
Callback failed: apex://accountSummaryLightningComponent/ACTION$getRelatedList` and tried with Owner[0]

Comment: @user81642 As in my previous answer, you should check if Task is a valid object: `row.Task && row.Task.length && row.Task[0].Owner? row.Task[0].Owner.Name: ''`